# Best way to *override* third party TypeScript types in node_modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

In many cases third party type definitions shipped either via a dedicated `@types/*` package or alongside the npm package itself are later found to be incomplete or incompatible with a new dependency.

I'm therefore looking for a *straightforward* way to override the types defined in `node_modules`. Ideally I'd just be able to copy paste them into my repo and tell the TypeScript compiler to use my types instead.

I've found 3 possible solutions but none are particularly great:

#### Declare *ambient* module

```
declare module 'printer' {
   export function print(msg: string): void;
}

declare module 'printer/color' {
   export function print(msg: string, color: string): void;
}

// WARNING: If you `import` or `export` anything here,
// this will suddenly *augment*, not *override* the
// 'printer' module.
```

###### Disadvantages

- Cannot simply copy and paste the broken types from `node_modules` because

  - You have to wrap it in `declare module 'printer' {}`
  - Sub-modules (e.g. `import print from 'printer/color'`) have to be explicitly declared as a separate module declaration.
  - Chances are the original types use `import` / `export` and therefore need to be rewritten to work within an ambient module.
- Can't *override* existing ambient modules (e.g. `declare module 'fs' {}` will merely *augment* types from `@types/node` not *override*)

#### Remap paths in tsconfig

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "baseUrl": "./",
  "paths": {
    "printer": ["types/printer"],
    "printer/color": ["types/printer/color"],
  }
}
```

###### Advantages

- Can literally just copy paste the types from node_modules verbatim and apply your own fixes.

###### Disadvantages

- Sub-modules (e.g. `import bar from 'printer/color'`) have to be explicitly declared as a separate path mapping.
- Can't *override* existing ambient modules (e.g. `@types/node`)

#### Install local package

```json
// package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "printer": "file:./packages/printer"
  }
}
```

##### Advantages

- Doesn't matter how the original types were written, they won't be installed

##### Disadvantages

- Although works well for dedicated `@types/*` packages, it's not suitable for packages which ship their own types as you'll effectively be taking ownership of the *runtime code*, meaning you'll miss security fixes etc.

The TypeScript docs don't seem to discuss solutions to this common problem but I wondered if anybody has a more robust solution with fewer caveats?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package

Comment: @KarolMajewski correct me if I'm wrong but would that have similar pro's / con's to installing a local package? i.e. you'd be maintaining the entire *code* not just the types?

Comment: Have you looked at `typeRoots`? https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots

Comment: @AlekseyL. I did use `typeRoots` to allow me to `declare module 'printer' {}` as per above, e.g. `"typeRoots": ["./types", "./node_modules/@types"]` but, even if I didn't include `"./node_modules/@types"` in `typeRoots`, importing the 'printer' module still seems to read from `@types/printer` or `printer/index.d.ts`. I think "typeRoots" is purely to pick up ambient modules?... but not 100% sure?

Comment: I think `typeRoots` effectively works like `types` but for entire directories and reading the docs for https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types it seems that yes, it won't impact types associated with an explicit `import`.

Comment: @riscarrott With `patch-package`, you can edit only the part you're interested in. You maintain the patch, not the entire library. You can upgrade the library and reuse the same patch, if needed. No need for copy-pasting anything and no risk of falling out of sync.